# How to delete unwanted lines from text file through batch file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a text file with following contents with some unwanted lines which I want to remove from the text file.

```
1233,pqry,01/11/2011
2365698,abcd,2011/01/12
,defghj,11/12/2013
,,,
,,,
,,,
```

In above example we can see there are multiple lines with comma separated. I want to remove those lines from my text file through batch file. Kindly help me out

Comment: you want to rid off `,,,` lines?

Comment: your lines are _not_ `comma separated`. Lines are separated by `CR/LF`.

Comment: @npocmaka : Yes I wanted to rid off from the lines which have only comma with no other values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ren myFile.txt myFile.txt.old
findstr /v /b /c:",,," myFile.txt.old > myFile.txt
```

Rename file as .old. Find all the lines not containing ",,," at the begin of line in old file and save it to original file.

EDITED - to adapt to comments

If lines to be removed are those with only commas (i will include spaces) and no other value, then this should work

```
for %%t in (c:\path\*.txt) do (
    ren "%%~ft" "%%~nxt.old"
    findstr /v /r /c:"^[, ]*$" "%%~ft.old" > "%%~ft"
)
```

For each file in path, rename the file to `*.old`, from this `.old` file extract any lines not containing (`/v`) the regular expression (`/r`) defined by the pattern (`/c`) : "from the start of line (`^`), followed by any sequence of spaces and commas (`[, ]*`) until reach the end of line (`$`)". The extracted lines are send to the original filename.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response but my problem is that,there may be a situation that they will be more or less than 3 comma... so in that case I guess it won't wrok

Comment: If there are more than three, this will match. The `/b` in the command says the match needs to be at the start of line, if you know that a single comma at the start of line is enough to discard the line, change `",,,"` to just `","`. Other options need to adapt the match expression.

Comment: I have edited my questions, there may be a situations where a line starts from , itself so in that situation it also delete that line...kindly look into that and suggest some new approach to me

Comment: Thanks for your response and one more elaboration the above question, If I don't want to mention the file name means for the particular directory this will act on all file within that directory... please help out of this...

Comment: Use a for command. `for %%t in (c:\somewhere\*.txt) do (....` and refer to the full name (including path) of file as `"%%~ft"`

Comment: I have tried your approach but it's not working for me. I have dobe like : for %%t in (c:\path\*.txt) do (findstr /v /r /c:"^[, ]*$" > "%%~ft" ). Can you please verify whether my approach is correct.

Comment: You had a problem with where to use the name of file. Answer updated to reflect the proper usage of variables.

Comment: It's not working for me... When I'm trying to run the batch file after modifying it then there is no output and DOS prompt went off instantly though I gave pause at end of batch file

Comment: Sorry, a typo error. I typed it directly inside the answer and forget to double percent signs, needed for batch file. Updated.